# Hold event on ListViewItem Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I've got an issue trying catching events on item from a ListView.

**WPF Sample**

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsListView" IsHoldingEnabled="True" 
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListItem}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="ItemSp" Holding="ItemSp_Holding">
                                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Modifier" />
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Supprimer" />
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  />
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**Code Behind Sample**

```
private void ItemSp_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("holded");
    }
```

**Style Sample**

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleListItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 2"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource FlashGreen}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SmoothDark}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Events aren't fired on Item (Tap or Hold, same problem).

Outside of these ListView events are working.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

**Full WPF UC**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MuchroomPhone.ShopItemsUC"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MuchroomPhone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="ItemsGrid">

            <ListView x:Name="itemsListView" IsHoldingEnabled="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListItem}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="ItemSp" Holding="ItemSp_Holding">
                                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Modifier" />
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Supprimer" />
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  />
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="NoItemsGrid">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource EmptyElemTextBox}">Aucun item</TextBlock>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="AddItemModal" Background="#AA000000" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="White"></Rectangle>
            <TextBox x:Name="NewItemTb" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" PlaceholderText="Nom de l'item" ></TextBox>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="CancelAddItemBtn" Click="CancelAddItemBtn_Click">Annuler</Button>
                <Button x:Name="AddItemBtn" Click="AddItemBtn_Click">Ajouter</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="addItem_Click">New Item</Button>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Show your SimpleListItem Style.

Comment: Do you think problems could occurs from this?

Comment: Is seems that problem not in this ListView, but in the parent element(s). I tried your sample and it works well.

Comment: It's working for real? Okay so I don't know what's wrong... I add the full code maybe you will see something weird...

Comment: The problem is in AddItemModal and NoItemsGrid. They should be in the separate row (not in the same row with ListView). You can remove them to test.

Comment: hey, I've tested, still the same, why do you think other Grid on same row can interferate with events? If you've tried, do you have the same problem than me when you have this additional grid on the template?

Answer (score 0):

working on nearly the same subject just now.. templated listviewitem inside templated usercontrol with handling listview events outside of usercontrol

code below will give me item_holding event outside usercontrol

inside loaded event
lv = Listview

//setting event handler to items in the view

```
   private void ConnectListView( ListView lv , SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged, HoldingEventHandler Item_holding)
    {
        lv.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lv.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (item != null)item.Holding += Item_holding;
        }
    }
```

// for items outside view in Listview ContainerContentChanging event

```
     private void LbContacts_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.ItemContainer.Holding -= lbContactsItem_Holding;
        args.ItemContainer.Holding += lbContactsItem_Holding;
    }
```

still playing around and testing, but it seems that it is working.
don't like to do this in ContainerContentChanging event because it is calling too frequently, but for now don't find another point.

Comment: I will try it in a bit, but i'm still surprised issue that simple isn't more discuss, I would say it would happend a lot!